# Nested logical && operator permissable?

Tags: c++, octave

I have written a .oct function for use in Octave that is not giving the result I expected and I think the problem might lie with the snippet of code given below - is it OK to nest the logical && operator as I have done or does it need to be separated out using further internal if loops?

```
 if ((( final_side_PDF > final_uwr_PDF && final_side_PDF > final_unr_PDF ) && final_side_PDF > final_dwr_PDF ) && final_side_PDF > final_dnr_PDF)
    {
    market_model(ii) = 0.0;
    }
 else if ((( final_uwr_PDF > final_side_PDF && final_uwr_PDF > final_unr_PDF ) && final_uwr_PDF > final_dwr_PDF ) && final_uwr_PDF > final_dnr_PDF )
    {
    market_model(ii) = 1.0;
    }
 else if ((( final_unr_PDF > final_side_PDF && final_unr_PDF > final_uwr_PDF ) && final_unr_PDF > final_dwr_PDF ) && final_unr_PDF > final_dnr_PDF)
    {
    market_model(ii) = 2.0;
    }
 else if ((( final_dwr_PDF > final_side_PDF && final_dwr_PDF > final_uwr_PDF ) && final_dwr_PDF > final_unr_PDF ) && final_dwr_PDF > final_dnr_PDF)
    {
    market_model(ii) = -1.0;
    }
 else if ((( final_dnr_PDF > final_side_PDF && final_dnr_PDF > final_uwr_PDF ) && final_dnr_PDF > final_unr_PDF ) && final_dnr_PDF > final_dwr_PDF)
    {
    market_model(ii) = -2.0;
    }
 else
    {
    market_model(ii) = market_model(ii-1);
    }
```

Edit in response to comments

I wish to check which one of the five variables; final_side_PDF, final_uwr_PDF, final_unr_PDF, final_dwr_PDF and final_dnr_PDF; has the largest value and to return a unique identifying number; 0,1,2,-1,-2; dependent on which one is the max. The above code is contained in a main (ii) loop.

Comment: It's OK you use "nested `&&`", but we cannot help you without knowing more details. Using `if-else if-else if-..-else` is very different from `if ..; if..; ...`. Depends on what you're trying to do (:

Comment: I think your code needs refactoring.. there are several relational checks that could easily be grouped which would lead to much much clearer code.

Comment: The code you posted does what you specified it should do, so the error must lie elsewhere. One thing you might try is to parenthesize each `final_xx_side > final_yy_size` check. The operator precedence rules say that `>` is evaluated before `&&` but I've come across at least one compiler that took a more free-spirited approach.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

```
 typedef int final_t;

 // From your code I assume that "final_xx" can have the same values, otherwise a std::map would be simpler. 
 std::multimap<final_t, double> finals;

 finals.insert(std::make_pair(final_side_PDF, 0.0));
 finals.insert(std::make_pair(final_uwr_PDF,  1.0));
 finals.insert(std::make_pair(final_unr_PDF,  2.0));
 finals.insert(std::make_pair(final_dwr_PDF, -1.0));
 finals.insert(std::make_pair(final_dnr_PDF, -2.0));

 auto max_final = finals.rbegin();

 if(finals.count(max_final->first) == 1)
    masket_model(ii) = max_final->second;
 else
    market_model(ii) = market_model(ii-1);
```

If "final_xx" all have unique values you can make it even simpler:

```
 typedef int final_t;

 std::map<final_t, double> finals;

 finals[final_side_PDF] =  0.0;
 finals[final_uwr_PDF]  =  1.0;
 finals[final_unr_PDF]  =  2.0;
 finals[final_dwr_PDF]  = -1.0;
 finals[final_dnr_PDF]  = -2.0;

 auto max_final = finals.rbegin();

 market_model(ii) = max_final->second;
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible that any two "final_xx" values could be the same, hence a default "market_model(ii) = market_model(ii-1);" in this case.
However, I do like your suggestion.